# Add default value in billing address checkout page Magento 2

Tags: checkout, address

I want to login customer address show in checkout page billing address.

See screen-short,

[image]

**`For Ex :-`** City is input-box and i want to show city name value.
If the customer is registered, then I want to get the of the customer added city.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: So in the city, you want to add a default city?

Comment: No, If the customer is registered, then I want to get the  of the customer added city.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly - IF the checkout is being done by a Registered-Customer (i.e. and NOT Guest-Checkout) AND they have a stored Shipping-Address ... THEN you want the City (associated with their Default-Shipping-Address) to be pre-populated in the checkout form ?

Comment: Yes,exactly right